# How to add a percent field in content type

Tags: 8, entities

Simple question. When creating a content type field, we have a float, decimal and integer number type, but how can we create a field with percentage type value, basically a range of 1-100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you not just create either a integer or float number field and just label the field as "percentage" or whatever? And also use the "suffix" option on the field options to add "%"

You can also set the min and max values of 0 to 100 to keep it within percentage range of options

Or how would you be expecting a percentage field to act different from a float/integer field?